# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'requireDirs.forEach')

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

So, I was transitioning code from windows to linux today to make sure everything works. I managed to break casper/phantom and I'm not even sure how.

Here's my command that runs a casper script on linux (ubuntu 12.14):

```
/usr/bin/casperjs /var/www/tekalyze/phantom/get_site_info.js --jquery-path="/var/www/tekalyze/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" --uri-path=" /var/www/tekalyze/phantom/URI.js" --log-path="/var/www/tekalyze/phantom/casper.log" --data-url=http://tekalyze.com/ajax.php --id='19' --url='http://www.bk.com/?utm_source=LOCATIONiq&utm_medium=locallstgs&utm_campaign=2013' --log-level=debug
```

It's giving me this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'requireDirs.forEach')
in module (./get_all_urls:102)
/var/www/tekalyze/phantom/get_all_urls.js:102 in _require
/var/www/tekalyze/phantom:13 in anonymous
/home/casper/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js:146 in _require
/var/www/tekalyze/phantom/get_site_info.js:8
/var/www/tekalyze/phantom/get_site_info.js:228
```

line 102 of get_all_urls is:

```
crawl.call(this, links[currentLink]);
```

I've tried commenting it out, and the stack trace remains the same, which leads me to believe it's not related.

The relevant file can be found [here](https://github.com/seiyria/grendel/blob/master/phantom/get_all_urls.js).

I'm honestly just scratching my head. I looked at bootstrap.js:146 and saw something about phantom.casperPath, but I hadn't had to set an environment variable in windows, so I'm not sure about this for linux. The [relevant line](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/bin/bootstrap.js#L146) is this: `if (!phantom.casperPath)` -- which leads me to believe I could get this to work if I re-write everything to start from phantom first, then set all of the casper variables, but I haven't verified whether or not that will work yet.

Also, I used [this](https://gist.github.com/shapeshed/5433860) script to install them both, so the directories should be set up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this functionality isn't added until 1.1.0-DEV, so updating to that instead of using 1.0.0 on linux is the best solution.